# ASP.net MVC 4 Runtime and Security Updates Keep Re-Installing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, windows-update

I know this is more of a systems issue and probably belongs on ServerFault, but because it strongly relates to ASP.net MVC web development I felt like someone was more likely to have encountered the same issue here.

I've uninstalled MVC, Visual Studio, and all of the related tools from the Program Manager. I went through the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" and disabled ASP.net, IIS, WCF, etc. I manually went through my AppData\Roaming, AppData\Local, AppData\LocalLow, Program Files, removing all the references to Visual Studio and MVC that I could find. Yet, every time Windows 10 performs Windows Update, it re-downloads the Microsoft **ASP.NET MVC 4 Runtime**, as well as **Microsoft ASP.Net Web Frameworks 5.0 Security Update (KB2992080)** and **Microsoft ASP.Net Web Frameworks 5.1 Security Update (KB2994397)** and re-installs them on my system. How do I get rid of these for good?

As a side-note, during this process I also found that dnx, SQL Server, and many other tools are not very good at cleaning up after themselves on uninstall. I found Gigabytes worth of files left behind :(